# Counting equivalence classes in the transitive closure of two equivalence relations

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, reference-request

Let $X$ be a finite set, and let $P_i$ and $Q_j$ be two partitions of $X$:

$$\bigsqcup_i P_i = \bigsqcup_j Q_j = X.$$

The finest partition which is nevertheless coarser than both $P$ and $Q$ is called their ``transitive closure''.

For the purposes of exposition, here is an example of two partitions of the set $X=\{1, 2,..., 8\}$.

$$X=\{1,2,3\} \sqcup \{4,5\} \sqcup \{6,7,8\}$$
$$X=\{1,3\} \sqcup \{2,4\} \sqcup \{5\} \sqcup \{6,7\} \sqcup \{8\}$$

We now form the incidence matrix of each partition.  Each row in the incidence matrix corresponds to a part of the partition; each column corresponds to an element of $X$.  The entry is a $1$ if the element is in the part, and $0$ otherwise:

$$T_P = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$$T_Q = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Finally, we stack these two matrices in a block matrix:

$$
T_{P \cup Q} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

But now we notice that the left nullspace of $T_{P \cup Q}$ is spanned by two vectors:

$$N_{P \cup Q} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and these vectors describe the parts of the transitive closure.  In particular, the dimension of the nullspace is the number of parts in the transitive closure.

Does anyone know a name for this lemma?  Does anyone have a reference?

Comment: Looks like your T-sub-q had what should be its first two rows compressed and flattened into one. There should be five rows, and there are only 4.